# How to exclude CustomValidator default message from ConstraintValidatorContext JavaX

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, validation

I have a custom validator that checks validations against the given Object and builds the
ConstraintValidatorContext, and if anything is violated then it builds the ConstraintViolationWithTemplate and adds the violated constraint message to the ConstraintValidatorContext context,
here in the constraint list, I could even see the default message which is in CustomerValidatorConstraint, I would like to exclude that CustomValidator default message

**Code**

public @interface ValidateItems {

```
    String message() default "Invalid Items object";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

}

@ValidateItems
private Items items;


public class Items {
    private int id;
    private String productName;
}


public class ValidItemValidator implements ConstraintValidator
        <ValidateItems, Items> {

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Items items, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {

        if (items.getProductName.startsWith("Z")) {
            context.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate("Product name should not start with Z").addConstraintViolation();
        }
    }
}
```

as shown in the above code, in the ConstraintValidatorContext object, I could see two constraint validation when I pass the product name starting with "Z"

1)Invalid Items object (Default custom validator message)

2)Product name should not start with Z (Actual Validation message)

**Requirement:**
I would like to exclude the default message from ConstraintValidator, Could someone help me with this?

Comment: @times29, Can you help me with this? thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I could able to solve this by disabling the default constraint violation

context.disableDefaultConstraintViolation();